# Most efficient way to implement numpy.in1d for muliple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, indexing

What is the best way to implement a function which takes an arbitrary number of 1d arrays and returns a tuple containing the indices of the matching values (if any).

Here is some pseudo-code of what I want to do:

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 4, 3, 2])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
c = np.array([4, 2])

(ind_a, ind_b, ind_c) = return_equals(a, b, c)
# ind_a = [2, 4]
# ind_b = [1, 3]
# ind_c = [0, 1]

(ind_a, ind_b, ind_c) = return_equals(a, b, c, sorted_by=a)
# ind_a = [2, 4]
# ind_b = [3, 1]
# ind_c = [0, 1]

def return_equals(*args, sorted_by=None):
    ...
```

Comment: Does it always have unique values within each of those input arrays?

Comment: The values are not sorted but unique yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `numpy.intersect1d` with `reduce` for this:

```
def return_equals(*arrays):
    matched = reduce(np.intersect1d, arrays)
    return np.array([np.where(np.in1d(array, matched))[0] for array in arrays])
```

`reduce` may be little slow here because we are creating intermediate NumPy arrays here(for large number of input it may be very slow), we can prevent this if we use Python's `set` and its `.intersection()` method:

```
matched = np.array(list(set(arrays[0]).intersection(*arrays[1:])))
```

---

Related GitHub ticket: [n-array versions of set operations, especially intersect1d](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5179)

Answer (score 1):

This solution basically concatenates all input `1D` arrays into one big `1D` array with the intention of performing the required operations in a `vectorized manner`. The only place where it uses loop is at the start where it gets the lengths of the input arrays, which must be minimal on runtime costs.

Here's the function implementation -

```
import numpy as np

def return_equals(*argv):
    # Concatenate input arrays into one big array for vectorized processing
    A = np.concatenate((argv[:]))

    # lengths of input arrays
    narr = len(argv)
    lens = np.zeros((1,narr),int).ravel()
    for i in range(narr):
        lens[i] = len(argv[i])  

    N = A.size

    # Start indices of each group of identical elements from different input arrays
    # in a sorted version of the huge concatenated input array
    start_idx = np.where(np.append([True],np.diff(np.sort(A))!=0))[0]

    # Runlengths of islands of identical elements
    runlens = np.diff(np.append(start_idx,N))

    # Starting and all indices of the positions in concatenate array that has 
    # islands of identical elements which are present across all input arrays
    good_start_idx = start_idx[runlens==narr]
    good_all_idx = good_start_idx[:,None] + np.arange(narr)

    # Get offsetted indices and sort them to get the desired output
    idx = np.argsort(A)[good_all_idx] - np.append([0],lens[:-1].cumsum())
    return np.sort(idx.T,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For start, I'd try:

```
def return_equals(*args):
    x=[]
    c=args[-1]
    for a in args:
        x.append(np.nonzero(np.in1d(a,c))[0])
    return x
```

If I add a `d=np.array([1,0,4,3,0])`  (it has only 1 match; what if there are no matches?)

then

```
return_equals(a,b,d,c)
```

produces:

```
[array([2, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 3], dtype=int32),
 array([2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int32)]
```

Since the length of both input and returned arrays can differ, you really can't vectorize the problem.  That is, it takes some special gymnastics to perform the operation across all inputs at once.  And if the number of arrays is small compared to their typical length, I wouldn't worry about speed.  Iterating a few times is not expensive.  It's iterating over a 100 values that's expensive.

You could, of course, pass the keyword arguments on to `in1d`.

It's not clear what you are trying to do with the `sorted_by` parameter.  Is that something that you could just as easily apply to the arrays before you pass them to this function?

---

List comprehension version of this iteration:

```
 [np.nonzero(np.in1d(x,c))[0] for x in [a,b,d,c]]
```

I can imagine concatenating the arrays into one longer one, applying `in1d`, and then splitting it up into subarrays.  There is a `np.split`, but it requires that you tell it how many elements to put in each sublist.  That means, somehow, determining how many matches there are for each argument.  Doing that without looping could be tricky.

The pieces for this (that still need to be packed as function) are:

```
args=[a,b,d,c]
lens=[len(x) for x in args]
abc=np.concatenate(args)
C=np.cumsum(lens)
I=np.nonzero(np.in1d(abc,c))[0]
S=np.split(I,(2,4,5))
[S[0],S[1]-C[0],S[2]-C[1],S[3]-C[2]]

I
# array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 12, 15, 16], dtype=int32)
C
# array([ 5, 10, 15, 17], dtype=int32)
```

The `(2,4,5)` are the number of elements of `I` between successive values of `C`, i.e. the number of elements that match for each of `a`,`b`,...

Comment: How is `d` determined?

Comment: `d` was just another sample, to give a case where the number of finds was not 2.  I was trying to generalize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
def return_equal(*args):
    rtr=[]
    for i, arr in enumerate(args):
        rtr.append([j for j, e in enumerate(arr) if 
                    all(e in a for a in args[0:i]) and 
                    all(e in a for a in args[i+1:])])
    return rtr    

>>> return_equal(a,b,c) 
[[2, 4], [1, 3], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: Is this intentionally a non-numpy approach?

Comment: Oddly, it is actually faster than all numpy in my timing, but I would not say that is obvious. Ashwini Chaudhary's second suggestion of using `set(a).intersection(b,c)` is also fast, but also mostly Python vs all numpy...

Comment: `np.in1d` takes time to sort and `unique` arrays, so it has overhead.  Especially for small tests a pure list operation often is faster than a `numpy` one.